# Magento2.2.x Custom page side bar in display mini cart items

Tags: magento2, addtocart, mini-cart, magento2.2.3

My custom page in displaying all product with add to cart product functionalities I want display mini cart items on page sidebar. after add to cart item update and display in that sections.

like that.
[image]

Comment: I saw you reloaded the cart section already. In this case, we should check the browser error.

Comment: Thanks, @KhoaTruongDinh. one thing I saw add to cart is configurable simple products that's why it's happening?

Comment: question updated

Comment: So, those products are configurable simple products, right?

Comment: all product....